# delete all test tags from git repo automatically

Tags: git, bash

I want to delete all tags from production git repo with the tags that include "_TEST".

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMITS_TO_REMOVE=$(git ls-remote git@github.com:REPONAME | grep _test | cut -f1)
COMMITS_TO_REMOVE_NO_CRLF=$(echo "$COMMITS_TO_REMOVE" | tr '\n' ' ')
for c in $COMMITS_TO_REMOVE_NO_CRLF 
do
    git tag -d $c;
    git push origin $c;
done;
```

but:

1) the COMMITS_TO_REMOVE_NO_CRLF isn't split by the spaces when running "for c in ..."

2) when I tried to push back the tags it didn't take.

ideas ?

Comment: probably because you're missing `git push --tags`, though if you're deleting tags you aught to be doing `git push :tagname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `COMMITS_TO_REMOVE_NO_CRLF`, bash takes newlines as whitespace.

You can delete the tags and, since at least 1.7, push the deletes in big batches with `xargs`.

Combining,

```
commits=$(git ls-remote $remote | sed -n '/_test[^^]*$/ s,.*refs/tags/,,p')
echo "$commits" | xargs tag -d
echo "$commits" | xargs git push --delete git@github.com:repo
```